# Using regular expression in Django templates

Tags: regex, django, django-templates

I wonder if it is possible using regular expression in Django templates:

```
<a href="#{{form.deal_template_name.value}} ????" data-toggle="tab">{{form.deal_template_name.value}}</a>
```

I would like to replace both spaces and dot's with _. (Otherwise the link would have trouble with the target)

```
{{form.deal_template_name.value}}

.replace(/ /g,"_").replace(/\./g,"_")
```

How to do that though in template directly, is that possible?

Comment: Please take a step back and think about this: Templates receive prepared data, so what you pass to a template should alreay have received that change in the code. So only do this if you are sure it is necessary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you really want to shoot yourself in the foot:

[Custom django filter](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/60/) that does that:

```
{% load replace %} {{ mystring|replace:"/l(u+)pin/m\1gen" }}
```

Comment: Thanks. Why shooting myself in the foot?

Comment: Ok, maybe isn't that bad :) Django way of doing things (tm) is that template language isn't a full programming language by design and that you should process your data in your view. As such running regexp in your code would be seen as trying to do php like mixing of html and business logic code.

Comment: I have actually found out that Django supports what I am trying to achieve out of the box -> `|slugify` :) But still its good to know how to achieve regular expressions in templates. Just in order to understand; if I was going to stick with this regex after all, how would I translate `.replace(/ /g,"_")` in `mystring|replace:"???"`

Comment: from docs: {% load replace %} {{ mystring|replace:"/l(u+)pin/m\1gen" }}
so: |replace:"/ /g,\"_\""