# filtering the main domain name

Tags: html, django

`<span>Source <a href="{{magazine_article.article.actual_source}}">{{context_data.brand_obj.brand_name}}</a></span>`

I want to filter out any particular name from any Url. How can i do it in Django. For example i want to filter out the name "youtube" from the link "https://www.youtube.com/".
Actually i am new to django .I am adding the example code and don't have any idea what to write in place of "{{context_data.brand_obj.brand_name}}" part so that i can filter out only some specific namefrom the whole URL. Thanks in advance. I have added the respective code above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using regular expression in Django templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582715/using-regular-expression-in-django-templates)

Comment: If you want to do this with django's template language, you have to write a custom template filter. With jinja2, this is a built in filter. http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#replace

Comment: @HåkenLid sir can you elaborate it? I am not able to write custom filter for this problem. How to use "relpace" for filtering the name "youtube" from  "https://www.youtube.com/"